# C# DataTable.WriteXml and DataSet.ReadXml check completion

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using a DataTable.WriteXml() and DataSet.ReadXml() methods.

My question is, Is there any way to check that Xml File creation is fully completed? I somewhat feels like there a something thread is holding it and a mainthread is passing it.

here is my code.

```cs
private void SaveDataToXml()
{
    //i want to check below WriteXml code completion
    this.DesignExplorerTable.WriteXml("C:\\SomethingFile.xml");

    //i think below code is excuted before above code is completed...
    this.SomethingMethod();
}
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you think `WriteXml` runs asynchronously? Are data missing in the file that are present in the `DataTable`? Does `SomethingMethod` depend on the results of `WriteXml`?

Comment: the WriteXml works right. As you said SomethingMethod seems like it depends on it. The SomethingMethod invokes other method that calls the result of the xml file. i guessed the OtherMethod reads it before the WriteXml creation.